# Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Im getting this error and I don't understand why.
The js seems to be right to me. Clearly Im missing something.
Any help would be appreciated.

JS:

```
            var doPostBack = function(UserId, TokenKey, opcao)
            {
                $.ajax({
                type: ""POST"",
                url: ""https://localhost:44382/Home/do_PostBack"", 
                data: {UserId: UserId, TokenKey: TokenKey, opcao: opcao}, 
                contentType: ""application/json; charset=utf-8"",
                success: function() {
                    
                    },
                failure: function() {
                        
                    },
                error: function() {
                        
                    }
                });
            }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:do_PostBack({TokenId}, {TokenKey}, {11})">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mismatch function name and parameter

```
<a href="javascript:do_PostBack(TokenId, TokenKey, 11)">Api Call</a>
```

`JSON.stringify` data before sending. You can also use property shorthand.

```
var do_PostBack = function(UserId, TokenKey, opcao)
{
    console.log(UserId, TokenKey, opcao);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://localhost:44382/Home/do_PostBack", 
        data: JSON.stringify({ UserId, TokenKey, opcao }), 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function() {

        },
        failure: function() {

        },
        error: function() {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't notice the function name was wrong. I fixed it but the error presists...

Comment: same error of `expected expression, got ','`, can Share screenshot of error?

Comment: @JuniorDevCaput Check out this demo example. https://jsfiddle.net/navnathjadhav/zykrabvd/138/

Comment: I was hable to fix it by changing the data to: data: '{TokenId: ""' + TokenId + '"", opcao: ""' + opcao + '"" }',

Comment: Ok. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, if it solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

There are double quotation marks in the type, url and contentType fields. This would make it invalid.

Below is the fixed function. I also changed 'var'to 'let'. But make sure this would not brake anything in your application.

```js
let doPostBack = function(UserId, TokenKey, opcao) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://localhost:44382/Home/do_PostBack",
    data: {
      UserId: UserId,
      TokenKey: TokenKey,
      opcao: opcao
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function() {

    },
    failure: function() {

    },
    error: function() {

    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Im doing this is a Class in c#, the reason for the double quotes is that it translates to a single quote within @"htmlString". Any other idea?

Comment: @navnath-jadhav answer seems to be what is going on.